# Ruby: Print JSON payload object with truncation

Tags: ruby, pretty-print

I am sending long payloads to API (Google Spreadsheets) and when that fails, I want to print the payload I sent.

The problem is when there is a lot of data I don't want to store all of it, I want the long arrays truncated any way possible.

Rxample payload:

```
{
  requests: {
    do_short_change: {
      attribute: "value",
      attribute: "value",
      attribute: { seomthing: "value" },
    }
    do_long_change: {
      attribute: "value",
      attribute: "value",
      attribute: { seomthing: "value" },
      rows: [], # <--- this contains a ton of data
    }
  }
}
```

Example result:

```
{
  requests: {
    do_short_change: {
      attribute: "value",
      attribute: "value",
      attribute: { seomthing: "value" },
    }
    do_long_change: {
      attribute: "value",
      attribute: "value",
      attribute: { seomthing: "value" },
      rows: Array(12000 items), # <--- the description is optional
    }
  }
}
```

so far I've narrowed my search to:

- overriding the `pretty_print(pp)` method on array (too broad of modification), or
- finding another JSON/geral prettifier that I can more easily and locally modify

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve somewhat decent output using `awesome_print` with `limit`.

```rb
puts requests.ai(indent: -2, limit: 4, plain: true, index: false)
```